# How to rename default django model field after creation in admin panel

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I am making a simple application in Django, where I want my admins to be able to go into the admin panel and create a **Level** object

```
class Level(models.Model):
        content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

^^ This is my simple layout for the model, only admins can create this.

However, when my admins create the **Level** object, it shows up like this:

[How it shows up in admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMXBv.png)

I don't want this, and I want that to be replaced with the string *content*, which is a field in my **Level** model

So instead of looking like above, I want it to just contain the *context*.

How can I do this?

Comment: can someone please help me I am so stuck on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the string to be the content:

```
class Level(models.Model):
        content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.content}"
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? What does __str__ mean

Comment: I dont understand the function u added

Comment: `__str__()` is a method that returns a string representation of an object. So this is presented whenever an instance of this object is shown in the admin portal. We are just just overriding this and returning a string of `f"{self.content}` where self is the object instance and content is whatever its content value is. You can obviously customise what this function returns to be whatever you want - the above is based on your request that it shows `content`

Comment: thank you very much brother amigo this worked very good its a very good solution to the demographic problems of India

Answer (score 0):

```
class Level(models.Model):
      content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.content
```

Comment: Can you plase explain how this works good sir? I dont understand the function you added

Comment: This method returns the string representation of the object. for details refer this https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-str-method-in-python